# Why this edit was accepted?

Tags: discussion

https://serverfault.com/posts/1101435/timeline

I don't understand why talks about "pwsh", what the hell is it? Powershell? Windows? Why was it added? Why this particular answer? This question explicitly says "on a Linux box" and has a tag "linux".

Besides that, it is awfully formatted and looks just bad.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edit wasn't accepted, it was made by the post author so there was no review needed.  If you want to know why they made the edit, you can ask them in a comment, and if you want to give feedback on their post and/or the edits, you can either comment or vote appropriately.

Comment: Well, I missed that it was edited by the author.